# camerax change image rotation based on device orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am implementing a basic camera using the CameraX API, but I am unable to understand how to achieve this. I am taking the device's orientation while clicking the picture using the code below.

```
imageCapture.takePicture(
ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()),
object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {

    override fun onCaptureSuccess(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        // Rotation matrix based on current readings from accelerometer and magnetometer.
        val rotationMatrix = FloatArray(9)
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(
            rotationMatrix,
            null,
            accelerometerReading,
            magnetometerReading
        )

        // Express the updated rotation matrix as three orientation angles.
        val orientationAngles = FloatArray(3)
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationAngles)

        imageProxy.close()
    }
})
```

`SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationAngles)` always returns an array of zeros no matter how I hold the physical device.

My activity has a locked orientation. Is there a better approach to image orientation?

Comment: You can't read a rotation angle if you are preventing it from ever rotating.  You should either get 0 or 90 and always get the same value, depending on which orientation you are locked to.  Note that on some newer devices you can also read the orientation of the sensor but it really doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @JohnLord so device accelerometer is turned off when activity rotation is locked in AndroidManifest?

Comment: If you use the CameraController API, the captured image will have the right rotation. You can get the rotation via: ImageProxy#ImageInfo#getRotationDegrees()

Comment: I believe it simply quits reporting to that activity.  You can lock activities individually, and in fact, it's quite common to do so, especially with camera functionality built in.  Our main app locks most screens to portrait but the document scanner and camera are in landscape to make use with opencv easier.